# What is the dimension of $\mathcal f(X,V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $V$ a vector space of dimension $3$. What is the dimension of $\mathcal F(X,V)$ (set of function $X\to V$) and give a base of it.

---

I can imagine that it's $3n$ the dimension, but how can I get a base of it ? I tried to find linear independent function that generate the space, but I don't really see how it work.

Comment: Presumably the elements of $X$ are the same as the field that $V$ is over?

Comment: Let $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ be a basis for $V$. For $1 \leq i \leq n,1\leq j \leq 3$ define $f_{ij}$ by $f_{ij} (x_k)=v_j$ if $x=x_i$ and 0 for any other $x$. There are $3n$ of these functions. can you verify that these form a basis?